# Eliminate time value from date field and change the format while fetching data from database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, date, ms-access

My program fetches few columns from Access database and displays the data in `JTable`. It works fine but I need to make some changes while data display. Like, in spite of storing the data in the form of dd-MM-yyyy in Access databse, it displays in the form **yyyy-MM-dd tt:tt:tt** format while retrieving. I need to display in the form of **dd-MM-yyyy** in the table. This date field is represented in the 1st column of table as `for_date`.

```
sql = "Select for_date as FOR_DATE,outage_time as OUTAGE_TIME,stat_detail as STATION_DETAILS from " + table_sel + " where for_date='" + date1 + "' and stat_detail ='" + combo_sel + "'";
Connection con = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Dell_PC\\Documents\\SYSTEM_OUTAGE_REPORT.accdb";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
st = con.createStatement();
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
con.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the date when retrieving it:

```
Select Format(for_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as FOR_DATE,outage_time as OUTAGE_TIME,stat_detail as STATION_DETAILS from " + table_sel + " where for_date='" + date1 + "' and stat_detail ='" + combo_sel + "'"
```

Comment: Hi Brian ! I tried your suggestion but somehow it gives me a syntax error. (; expected)Don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Ok, so I finally figured out how to display it with your help. the dd/mm/yyyy should have been within single quotes !   Select Format(for_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as FOR_DATE,outage_time as OUTAGE_TIME,stat_detail as STATION_DETAILS from " + table_sel + " where for_date='" + date1 + "' and stat_detail ='" + combo_sel + "'"

Comment: Don't rely on the database to do the conversion. Use a render.

Answer (score 1):

I am being a bit vague here because I have no experience with UCanAccess JDBC driver. As I understand, you are using this. However, I believe that this thread of answers is not complete as long as no one has mentioned the modern way of solving this task. The modern way involves minimizing the use of the outdated class `Date`, dropping it completely if you can, and using `java.time.LocalDate` instead.

So the first step is to check whether a new version of UCanAccess conforms with JDBC 4.2. If so, it can directly give you a `LocalDate` object instead of a `Date` object. So I’ve read. If this is not an option, first thing after you got hold of your `Date` is to convert it with `yourDate.toLocalDate()`. This ought to be the job of your `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel()`. However I am not sure whether this is your own method for you to modify or a method in some standard library.

With a `LocalDate` we’re almost there. This will default display as `yyyy-MM-dd`. You wanted it the other way around, `dd-MM-yyyy`. For this, I tend to agree with Robin and camickr that you should use a table renderer.  Your renderer should use a

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
```

To format your `LocalDate` it would do

```
yourLocalDate.format(dateFormatter);
```

or if you have not had a chance to convert a `Date` yet, then of course

```
yourDate.toLocalDate().format(dateFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `TableCellRenderer` for that column using the [`JTable#setDefaultRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultRenderer-java.lang.Class-javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer-). For formatting your dates in your renderer, you can use a `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with simple date format to change one format to another

```
String date_s = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";

    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date date = dt.parse(date_s);


    SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

Comment: Hi gati ! Where do I need to place this code as I am displaying it in jTable. Could you kindly show me.

Comment: Can you please try some thing like this   public class DateCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        public DateCellRenderer() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(final Object value) {
            final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

            strValue = sdf.format(value);
            }
            super.setText(strValue);
        }
    }

Comment: @gatisahu, Don't put code in a comment. As you have noticed the code is not readable. Your answer can always be edited. Also don't create the SimpleDateFormat object in the renderer code as this method is invoked continuously. Make the SimpleDataFormat on instance of the class as demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a custom renderer to format the date. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for basic information on using a renderer with a table.

A basic renderer would be:

```
public class YMDRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    private Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd");

    public void setValue(Object value)
    {
        //  Format the Object before setting its value in the renderer

        try
        {
            if (value != null)
                value = formatter.format(value);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {}

        super.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Also, Check out [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for reusable classes that allow you to easily date, time, number just by providing a `FormatRenderer`.